# Unable to test Jenkins plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am actually trying to develop a Jenkins plugin using maven but I am unable to test it.

I created my project with the command `mvn -cpu hpi:create`. I called the `project jenkins-plugin-tutorial`. I packaged it with `mvn package` or `mvn install` and run the Jenkins server with `mvn hpi:run`.

By default, there is a HelloWorlBuilder for testing purpose that should appear at the Jenkins configuration page (Jenkins Menu -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System) or under the Build section, but it does not display.

I followed these two tutorials ([here](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/08/tutorial-create-a-jenkins-plugin-to-integrate-jenkins-and-nexus-repository/) and [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial))  step by step many times by making sure that I do not make a mistake but it still dont work.

Maybe I have made something wrong. Can somebody gives me some hint how to correct my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the answer to my questions. The problem is that I was using an old version of maven, the 2.2.1 version. So I change to the last version, 3.0.4, everything is fine now.

Answer (score 5):

In `pom.xml`, try changing parent to this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.454</version>
</parent>
```

I just did quick test with that hpi:create, and it worked for me, I got both global and job config things as expected, but I had to do that change to pom.xml, before I got it to compile.

That is, I did:

- `mvn hpi:create`
- entered groupId `foo.hyde.jenkins.plugins`, artifactId `hello-world` when prompted.
- `cd hello-world`
- `mvn install` failed
- Edit pom.xml to change the parent
- `mvn install` succeeded
- `mvn hpi:run -Djetty.port=8092` succeeded (Using that port because other Jenkins is already in default port, otherwise -D... not needed.)
- Go to `http://localhost:8092`, check global config, create job and add the build step

And it worked for me.

I'm using Maven 2, version 2.2.1.